# Why zero energy is possible and what determines that particles have ground state energy equal to zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In some cases particles have ground state energy  equal to zero like particle on a circle . In other cases, like particle in a box or harmonic oscillator, it can never have zero ground state energy.

I have three questions regarding this scenario

1. What condition  determines for the particles to have ground state energy equal to zero?
2. Why zero energy is allowed? It isn't possible classically, but why quantum mechanically it is and how having zero energy does not violate laws of physics?
3. Why in the specific case of bosons ground state energy is taken to be zero when they form Bose Einstein condensate ?

Comment: What do you mean 'zero energy isn't allowed classically'?

Comment: I mean if it's energy is zero then it's mass and momentum will be zero classically.

Comment: Why are we bringing mass into this? The quantum mechanics you're describing is non-relativistic.

Comment: Yes I'm discussing non relativistic quantum mechanics. I am confused that in classical mechanics we don't have any example of having zero energy but in quantum mechanics we have and why this is so?

Comment: But the non-relavistic analogs of those scenarios do have zero energies. It's only if you do it relavistically and add in a mass term that they can't do. Likewise, if you did the QM relativistically there would also be a mass term preventing a zero energy solution.